# SQL Merge matching rows in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here is my table schema

```
Table1
{
Column1 nVarchar(Max),
Column2 nVarchar(Max)
}
```

Here is my  sample Data

```
Column1            Column2

Tom                Blue
Tom                
Gary               Green
Gary               Yellow
Sam                 
Sam                Red
```

i would like to update the Column2 if the column1 value is duplcated and either one of rows in column2 is empty , the empty cell will be replaced by non empty cell.

For example i the desired output from above sample data will be

```
 Column1            Column2

    Tom                Blue
    Tom                Blue
    Gary               Green
    Gary               Yellow
    Sam                Red 
    Sam                Red
```

Comment: What should happen if you have three rows with one `NULL` and the other two different values?

Comment: When you say "empty" do you mean null or zero length string or either?

Comment: I mean empty string ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below will update with the maximum value, Ignoring nulls or empty strings.

If there is only one distinct possibility than that of course will be the one that is chosen.

```
;WITH T AS 
(
SELECT *, 
       MAX(NULLIF(Column2,'')) OVER (PARTITION BY Column1) AS C2
FROM YourTable
)
UPDATE T
SET Column2 = C2
WHERE Column2 IS NULL OR Column2 = '';
```

Comment: consider what if the values are not null, but the empty string `''`

Comment: @JeffPuckettII the question isn't clear on that point so updated to treat either null or zero length string as "empty"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Column2 =
    (SELECT t1.Column2 FROM Table1 t1
     WHERE t1.Column1 = Table1.Column1
     AND t1.Column2 IS NOT NULL)
WHERE Column2 IS NULL
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 'OTHER'
    FROM Table1 t1
    WHERE t1.Column1 = Table1.Column1
    and t1.Column2 IS NOT NULL)
```